# Spring MVC : Mapping Form input to complex backing object containing HashMap

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have scenario where a list of input fields from the jsp form would map to a HashMap field within the backing object Resolution.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/rms") 
    class ResolutionManagementController{

        private static final String ISSUE_FORM_PATH="/view/resolutionForm";
        private static final String SHOW_RESOLUTION_PATH="/view/showResolution";

        @Autowired
        IIssueManagementService issueService;

        @Autowired
        ResolutionManagementService resolutionService;

        @RequestMapping(value="/resolution/form",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        String resolutionForm(Model model){
                List<Issue> issues = issueService.listIssue();
                model.addAttribute("issues",issues);
                model.addAttribute("resolution", new Resolution());
                return ISSUE_FORM_PATH;     
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/resolution",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        String resolve(Resolution resolution,Model model){
            List<SupportExecutive> executives = resolutionService.addResolution(resolution);
            model.addAttribute("executives",executives);
            return SHOW_RESOLUTION_PATH;
        }   

    }
```

Backing Form Object

```
class Resolution{
        private String resolutionId;
        private String categoryId;
        private Map<Issue,SupportExecutive> allotments;

        //getters and setters

    }
```

resolutionForm.jsp

```
<form:form action="/rms/resolution" commandName="resolution">

        <c:forEach var="issue" items="${issues}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${issue.issueTitle}
                </td>
                <td>
<!-- What should i do so that issueTitle is converted
to Issue Object and stored as map key in allotments Map in resolution 
object and the value entered by the user is converted to SupportExecutive 
object and stored as corresponding value object of the allotments map-->
                    <input type="text" name="${issue.issueTitle}>"
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>


    </form:form>
```

I tried to take a look at property editors but i am unable to understand how would i obtain the key and value and store in the map using property editor. Or may be they are not suited here.

What is the most cleanest way of achieving this ? It would be good if a detail explanation involving steps can be provided.

Comment: Why don't you use a more suitable object (something like a DTO with issue data and list of allotments). It's always better to avoid jsp "code"

Comment: can you explain, how you expect me to use DTO here. how can it help simplify binding form data to an allotments map?

Comment: I understand what you trying to say. I personally avoid usage of DTO since they are not part of domain model. I try to follow the Rest Principle as much as possible where a request deals with a resource (domain objects, eg: add/student, update/student, add/employee, update/employee) but we never do add/dto or update/dto. Thats kind of complicating things. Its more of personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of one way to hook up a property editor for your domain class:

```
package your.controller.package;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
...
public class YourController {
    ...
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Resolution.class, new ResolutionFormEditor());
    }

    private static class ResolutionFormEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
        // convert a Resolution object to a string type
        @Override public String getAsText() {
            Resolution r = (Resolution) this.getValue();
            return r != null ? r.resolutionId() : "";
        }  

        // convert string representation to Resolution object
        @Override public void setAsText(String text) {
            Resolution r = resolutionService.findById(text);
            this.setValue(r);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

[Spring property editor documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) has a good description.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I forgot about the Map part of your question. Take a look at [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/15960-binding-hashmap-attribute-to-html-form) for example code.

Comment: In your example, where are the input parameters from the form received. the name attributes of <input> must be used as key and value entered by the user must used as value. In the UI there will be a list of issues titles in tabular form and a user would simply enter the name of the executive against each issue. Now issue title becomes the key of the allotment map and the name of the executive entered becomes the value of the map. but the key and the value must be converted to corresponding objects like Issue and SupportExecutive objects.

Comment: say if i get HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() i can extract the param name (say issuetitle) and convert it to Issue iss = new Issue(); iss.setTitle(issueTitle). This becomes key for the allotments map in resolution object. Similary they value received against issueTitle (say executiveName) can be converted as SupportExecutive executive = new SupportExecutive(), executive.setName(executiveName), executive is value for the allotments map.